# Passing a hexadecimal value into a module

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I created a module that accepts a wire `[  4 : 0 ]` as input, and I'm using several instances of this module.  But, I'm getting:

> Syntax error in instance port expression(s)

whenever I pass a value that contains A-F.

For example:

```
key_schedule i1(09); // works
key_schedule i1(0A); // doesn't work
key_schedule i1(15); // works
key_schedule i1(1D); // doesn't work
```

If anyone knows what's wrong, I'd appreciate their help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Verilog treats all bare numeric literals as decimal.  `A` and `D` are not legal decimal values.

For hexadecimal literals, you need to specify the literal type using `'h`:

```
key_schedule i1('h0A); // works
key_schedule i1('h1D); // works
```

Refer to the IEEE Std (1800-2009, for example), section "Numbers".

The following code compiles for me without errors on 2 different simulators (Incisive and VCS):

```
module tb;
    key_schedule i1(5'h1A);
    key_schedule i2('h1A);
endmodule

module key_schedule (input [4:0] in);
    always @(in) $display(in);
endmodule
```

Answer (score 8):

From http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/syntax1.html#Integer_Numbers

Verilog HDL allows integer numbers to be specified as

- Sized or unsized numbers (Unsized size is 32 bits)
- In a radix of binary, octal, decimal, or hexadecimal
- Radix and hex digits (a,b,c,d,e,f) are case insensitive
- Spaces are allowed between the size, radix and value

Syntax:

```
[size]'[radix][value];
```

Example:

```
8'h1D;   # 8-bit hex value "1D"
```

Comment: I saw this "'h" used even before I asked and tried it as well, but it didn't work either. I'm getting "error: unmatched character (hex ?)"